# Importing Data in SQL Server from an API that uses a token call

Tags: sql-server, import, ssis, ssis-2012

I am trying to import data into a sql server table that comes from a web api utilizing SSIS but open to other methods.  I first need to send a token call with my unique ID in the URL and then send a new call with that token ID in the URL for the data.   The token is only active for 30 minutes and I am looking to do this hourly.   Any direction anyone could provide would be highly appreciated

Comment: I think you're going to need to be more specific before anyone can help.

Comment: A lot of people have done this. You'll need to use a script source and personally I think it's pretty horrible. Here is one example. https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/22587.consume-webservice-via-ssis-script-component.aspx It doesn't deal with expiring tokens but really that is just some more C# code. I suggest you put down some code and ask some specific questions. I actually also suggest you build this in a console app since most of what you're doing is C# code and the SSIS piece doesn't add any benefit.

Comment: Thank you. C# and development isn't my world is why I didn't put in code down. It's not that I didn't attempt but was looking for a better starting place before adding some code that hopefully will be in the right direction